# $\langle Pu,v \rangle = \langle u, Pv\rangle \quad \forall u,v \in H$ then $P$ is the orthogonal projection

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

I am wondering if my proof of the following exercise is valid

> [Royden 16.9] Let $V$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ and $T$ a projection of $H$ onto $V$. Show that $T$ is the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $V$ if and only if $\langle Tu,v \rangle = \langle u, Tv \rangle \quad \forall u,v \in H$.

Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $V$. Then for $u,v \in H$,

$$
\langle (T-P)(u), v\rangle = \langle Tu,v \rangle - \langle Pu,v \rangle = \langle u, Tv \rangle - \langle u,Pv \rangle = \langle 0, Tv-Pv\rangle =0
$$

Which implies $T=P$. By Proposition 5, $P$ satisfies $\langle Pu,v \rangle = \langle u, Pv \rangle \quad \forall u,v \in H$.

Comment: I think you made an error when working with your inner products: $\langle u, Tv \rangle - \langle u, Pv \rangle = \langle u, (T - P) v \rangle$

Comment: @StephenDonovan ah thank you I see that now. I’m a bit stuck on this problem. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Can you state what definition of an orthogonal projection you're using? The definition I'm looking at defines an orthogonal projection in this way. (but I can say that defining it as "the" orthogonal projection seems incorrect - clearly it can't be unique because linear combinations of such projections also have this property)

Comment: @StephenDonovan the projection which sends each vector to the unique closest element of a nonempty closed convex subset. The existence of this element was proved in a previous theorem so the projection is unique.

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't see that we define that $T$ is a projection, I thought we were just allowing it to be a generic linear transformation. That was where I made my mistake, with the restriction that $T$ is a projection the solution can be unique again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given a projection $T$ of $H$ onto $V$. Therefore $T^2=T$. And $T$ is an orthogonal projection iff $(x-Tx)\perp V$ for all $x$, which is equivalent to
$$
            \langle x-Tx,Ty\rangle =0,\;\; x,y\in H.
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
           \langle x,Ty\rangle=\langle Tx,Ty\rangle,\;\; x,y\in H.
$$
This condition is equivalent to
$$
               \langle x,Ty\rangle = \langle Tx,y\rangle,\;\; x,y\in H.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you get your equality $\langle u, Tv \rangle - \langle u, Pv \rangle = \langle 0, Tv - Pv \rangle$. You also don't seem to have used the fact that $T$ is a projection. My solution follows: don't read if you don't want it spoiled.

You want to show $\langle u - Tu, v \rangle = 0$ for all $u \in H$ and $v \in V$. Since the projection is surjective we may write $v = Th$ for some $h \in H$. Then $\langle u - Tu, v \rangle = \langle u - Tu, Th \rangle = \langle u, Th \rangle - \langle Tu, Th \rangle$. Because $T$ is a projection, $T^2 = T$, so $\langle Tu, Th \rangle = \langle u, T^2 h \rangle = \langle u, Th \rangle$. Thus we have shown $\langle u - Tu, Th \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Why are you allowed to make no reference to the true unique orthogonal projection?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have shown $u - Tu$ is orthogonal to $V$, and since $T$ is a projection this means it is an orthogonal projection (which as you know is unique). There is no need to presuppose the existence of a orthogonal projection in the proof.